# is there a way to add new skin in django-ckeditor?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-ckeditor, django-static

I'm trying to add new skin in django-ckeditor but its doesnt work and it shows a blank screen in django-admin

I have installed the kama skin and extracted in static\ckeditor\ckeditor\skins\kama but doesnt seem to work.

Below im showing my ckeditor config options:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': None,
        'toolbarCanCollapse': True,
        'skin': 'kama',
        'uiColor': '#b7d6ec',
    },

}
```

Can someone please resolve this issue?I m very new to django ckeditor and its config and building my first website.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: If you have a blank screen, you probably have js errors, check your browser console, probably it can't find some resources

Comment: on console its saying "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).......................editor.css:1

Comment: did you run ```python manage.py collectstatic```?

Comment: yes but no change

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late but I managed to get my Office2013 skin working by mimicking CKEditor directory structure.

[image: ckeditor skin dir]

Answer (score 0):

```sh
django-admin collectstatic -c
```

This did the trick for me. It replaced an old bundle-aaaaaaaa.js file by another file that was found when I reloaded my page.

*(And then I discovered that my problem was that I had `moono-lisa` skin inside my `static/djangocms_ckeditor/ckeditor/skins` folder, but `moono` in my settings)*